# saving a image in database using blob in foreach

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created  dynamic textboxes, the other one has a type of file. My problem is 
that I don't know how to save the image in the database and have a copy of it inside a folder cause I'm gonna retrieve it later on. But since it's in an array form I don't have an idea how to do it. I used blob for it, but if you have better way , lets see. I know how to make a copy of inside a folder but I didn't use a foreach, this I don't know.
Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#append").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var textboxes = $(".textbox").length;
    $(".inc").append("<div class='controls'><input class='textbox  form-control' type='file' name='textbox[]'><input class='textbox form-control' type='text' name='box[]' ><input class='textbox form-control' type='text' name='box1[]' ><input class='textbox form-control' type='text' name='box2[]' ><a href='#' class='remove_this btn btn-danger'>remove</a> </div>");
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove_this', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).parent().remove();
});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method= "POST">
<div class="control-group">
<div class="inc">
    <div class="controls">
        <button style="margin-left: 50px" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="append" name="append">
        Add Textbox</button>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "lala";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$textboxes = $_POST['textbox'];
$textboxes1 = $_POST['box1'];
$textboxes2 = $_POST['box2'];
$boxes = $_POST['box'];
$textboxes=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['textboxes']['tmp_name']));
        $image_name1=addslashes($_FILES['textboxes']['name']);
        $image_size1=getimagesize($_FILES['textboxes']['tmp_name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['textboxes']['tmp_name'],"images/".$_FILES['textboxes']['name']);
        $location1="images/".$_FILES['textboxes']['name'];
foreach ($location1 as $key => $textbox ) {
    $box=$textboxes[$key];
    $box1=$textboxes1[$key];
    $box2=$textboxes2[$key];
    $sql = "INSERT into sasa (sasa,sasa1,sasa2,sasa3) values('$textbox','$box','$box1','$box2')";
    echo $sql . "<br>";
    $q = $conn->query($sql);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: U need to save file name in db ascseperate column $_FILES['textboxes']['name'];

Comment: Second u didnt use multipart encryptcin form

Comment: but i want to have a copy of the images in a folder where all the uploaded images are located, cause im gonna need it in my front end'

Comment: $location1 is not an array

Comment: File uploading properly??? In folder?

Comment: What errors r u getting?

Comment: yeah when i use multipart encryptcin form it works but only to those who are not inside the loop,

Comment: $location1="images/".$_FILES['textboxes']['name']; this is not an array y r u using foreach

Comment: it says invalid argument foreach and undefined colorpic

Comment: how to do it, i dont have any dea,

Comment: Do u have any column for saving image name?

Comment: please i really need to solve this.

Comment: yes, the first attribute is for the image name

Comment: i know how to do it if its not in array form, but this one is in array form since the adding textboxes is dynamic

Comment: Its an array or value $_POST['textbox'];

Comment: can you solve it for me?

Comment: But I need to know all field. How many fields in form?

Comment: yeah, you can see t in my code

Comment: I have checked now one last thing why r using box2[] as array all input fields u said its only four

Comment: everytime you click the add button 4 textboxes will appear .

Comment: its an dynamic way of adding and removing texboxes

Comment: Alright if I click again four more field will open

Comment: yeah, and i want the selected image for the type file will have a copy in the folder images